# O que é persistência de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, terminologia, persistência

O que seria esse termo? Eu sempre vejo por ai e não consigo decifrar!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Segundo o [artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persist%C3%AAncia_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)):

> É característica de um estado que sobrevive ao processo que o criou. Sem essa capacidade, o estado só existiria na RAM, e seria perdido quando a RAM parasse (desligando-se o computador, por exemplo).

É só um nome bonito pra dizer que gravou os dados em algum lugar e que não se perderá quando o computador for desligado (HDD, SSD, ou até na nuvem, por exemplo). É só uma forma de dizer que o dado ficará disponível "para sempre" sem dizer como.

Normalmente está ligado a banco de dados, mas é claro que não precisa ser em um, qualquer tipo de aplicação que grave qualquer coisa para que esse estado possa ser recuperado mais tarde está fazendo persistência. Não é algo ligado ao SQL, mas é claro que o SQL faz persistências, especialmente em `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://oloquei%20no%20**GitHub**%20para%20refer%C3%AAncia%20futura.).

Comment: É um paradoxo dizer que o DELETE faz persistência de dados, ( rsrs ) mas esta certo, de fato, faz. Faz a persistência de meu desejo de que esse dado seja excluído.

Comment: É isso mesmo, persistência é sobre o estado e não sobre o dado em si. Dizer que o dado não existe mais é uma mudança de estado que precisa ser persistida. Inclusive porque não é só apagar, ele grava rastros que isto foi feito (pelo menos em banco de dados costuma ocorrer, mas mesmo que não ocorresse, ainda valia).

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pelo seu tempo! Agora eu entendi esse paradigma hehe! 

Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Os dados em memória se perdem assim que o programa termina.

Para que esses dados não se percam é necessário que sejam gravados em um
dispositivo físico.

Portanto: a persistência de dados, na computação, refere-se ao armazenamento não-volátil de dados, por exemplo, o armazenamento em um dispositivo físico como um disco rígido.